# External USB keyboard layout doesn't match macOS input source language layout

Tags: mac, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I've recently purchased an external USB keyboard to use with my MacBook Pro 2016. However, when pressing some keys I have noticed they're not returning the expected character.

Further analysis suggests this issue happens because the external keyboard is compliant with ISO/IEC 9995, but the internal keyboard is not.

This is PT_PT ISO/IEC 9995, please notice the two keys between <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Ç</kbd>:

[image: PT_PT ISO/IEC 9995]

This is the PT_PT layout on macOS input source:

[image: PT_PT layout on macOS]

So my question is, how can I change the macOS layout of the external USB keyboard in order to match the keys I'm pressing? Preferably without messing up the internal one (to be used whenever unplugged).

I already have tried running the keyboard setup assistant, Karabiner app and checking other available Input Sources for Portuguese (PT) language.

Comment: If the physical layouts are different, especially if one is a Mac ANSI keyboard & the other a PC ISO, then you can't map both at the same time.